# Pass file path to javascript input android

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I understand that providing a physical file path to javascript is not possible due to security reasons. However, when I look at Mozilla's pdf.js and mupdf android pdf viewer I see this is very much possible. There is a mechanism by which I can pass a file path to javascript. I explored into PDF.js but it seemed little difficult to make use of when I needed a simple solution. 
I want to pass android internal storage file location onto the following code instead of using `input id="files" type="file"` which requires me to browse and select file. In my case I want to just pass file location from sdcard. 
The following code actually loads ms word (docx) file as html which I then will show in webview in my project. In the case of pdf.js we were using it to display pdf in the similar way.

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Input File
  var $files = $('#files');
  //File Change Event
  $files.on('change', function (e) {
    //File Object Information
    var files = e.target.files;
    //Create DocxJS
    var docxJS = new DocxJS();
    //File Parsing
    docxJS.parse(
      files[0],
      function () {
        //After Rendering
        docxJS.render($('#loaded-layout')[0], function (result) {
          if (result.isError) {
            console.log(result.msg);
          } else {
            console.log("Success Render");
          }
        });
      }, function (e) {
        console.log("Error!", e);
      }
    );
  });
});
</script>
<input id="files" type="file" name="files[]" multiple="false"  />
<div id="loaded-layout" style="width:100%;height:800px;">
</div>
```

You can check code of PDF.JS based pdfviewer in android [here](https://bitbucket.org/butelo/pdfviewer/src).

What I found on the PDF.js code which was used to input file : 
In pdffile.js included in index.html file, url variable was mentioned pointing to real location of the file i.e. in assets folder which then was used in pdf.js but at that point the usage seems confusing. Is there any way by which I can use real path of file or pass real path somehow in android for my purpose of viewing docx?

UPDATE : 
I find that PDF.js by Mozilla actually treats file location as a url and so the file in the url is converted to javascript file object or blob. Hence I create a blob of the url from server using Ajax :

```
     var myObject;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET","10143.docx",true); // adding true will make it work asynchronously
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
        if (this.status == 200){
            //do some stuff
            myObject = this.response;
        }
    };
    xhr.send();



    $(document).ready(function(){
    //Input File
  var $files = $('#files');

  //File Change Event
  $files.on('change', function (e) {

    //File Object Information
    var files = myObject.files;

    //Create DocxJS
    var docxJS = new DocxJS();

    //File Parsing
    docxJS.parse(
      blobToFile(myObject, "10143.docx"),
      function () {
        //After Rendering
        docxJS.render($('#loaded-layout')[0], function (result) {
          if (result.isError) {
            console.log(result.msg);
          } else {
            console.log("Success Render");
          }
        });
      }, function (e) {
        console.log("Error!", e);
      }
    );
  });
});

function blobToFile(theBlob, fileName){
    //A Blob() is almost a File() - it's just missing the two properties below which we will add
    theBlob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
    theBlob.name = fileName;
    return theBlob;
}
```

However now that I do that I get Parsing error from DocxJS like : `{isError: true, msg: "Parse Error."}`